# Postgres: how to detect out of space condition in query?

Tags: postgresql

Is there any libpq function to detect disk full (No space left on device) condition when `PQexec` fails for an `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a special function for that, it is part of the error message you get.

The SQLSTATE for “disk full” is `53100` (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html)).

If you have a `PGresult *res`, you can get the SQLSTATE with

```
PQresultErrorField(res, PG_DIAG_SQLSTATE);
```

See the [libpq documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PG-DIAG-SQLSTATE) for details.